# C++ Text Based Game regarding Classes [PACMAN game]

Tags: c++

I'm studying C++ and I've come across an issue that I can't seem to wrap my head around, I've looked up questions for inheritance for classes but I still do not understand.
The task given to me was to create a simple text-based Pacman game. However, there are a few requirements to meet that I cannot visualize coding for.

In the program: 
Entity Class : Abstract Class used for Player and Enemies (contains position class)

Map Class : Class containing array of map size (e.g array[15][15])

Position Class : contains coordinates of X and Y (int x, int y)

How can I set the coordinates of an entity, and update the entity coordinates onto the map array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no relationship between `Map` and `Entity` in what you have described, so that's for you to choose.

Comment: But if i wanted to update the map array with the coordinates of the entity, what are some methods that I can try out?

Comment: Update *what* in the map array? If I understand correctly, `Map` contains level geometry, not entities.

Comment: the array for the map is used to print out the space the entities will be moving around in. for e.g, I have to spawn an entity at the coordinates of (0,0) in the map array, and then print out that map array with a char at mapArray[0][0]. So if I had to implement player-movement into the game, I would need to constantly update the map. However, the current issue I have is that I do not know how to even set the spawnpoint for the character onto the map using the Position and Entity class into the Map class. sorry if all of this is unclear

Comment: An `Entity` knows its own coordinates, so each needs only a way to access the map. Then, when moving it'd change the map to remove its symbol from its old position (leaving a space instead) and setting it at its new one. Spawning an entity is just creating one in an empty space, and usig the same access to put its symbol at its position.

Comment: What are some of the methods to allow entity to access the map class?

Comment: Each `Entity` could hold a pointer to the map it is part of, or you could access the map through a global variable (not generally recommended, but could be fine for this small project).